# How to stop c++ implicitly converting double to bool?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have a struct that is a json library that has these as their constructors:

```
JSONValue(std::string input);
JSONValue(double input);
JSONValue(bool input);
JSONValue(std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input);
JSONValue(std::vector<JSONValue> input);
JSONValue(void* null_input);
```

if I were to run

```
JSONValue a = object();
a["key"] = (double)4.3;
```

and then print it, I would get the output `true` as a boolean value. There is an implicit conversion from double to bool when I explicitly do not want there to be. Even if I wan the following code:

```
double val = 4.3;
JSONValue a = object();
a["key"] = 4.3;
```

And then print it, I would get `true` again. How can I fix this?

For reference the `object` function creates what is similar to a dictionary in python.

What I have found does work is this:

```
a["key"] = JSONValue((double)4.3);
```

However, what I want to be able to do is just do this:

```
JSONValue a = object();
a["key"] = 4.3;
```

And not have it converted to a boolean object.

*EDIT*

JSONValue::operator[] returns another JSONValue object
This is the entire struct without the functions defined:

```
enum class JSONValueType { String, Number, Object, Array, Boolean, Null };
struct JSONValue{
    std::optional<std::string> string;
    std::optional<double> number;
    std::optional<bool> boolean;
    std::optional<std::vector<JSONValue>> array;
    std::optional<std::map<std::string, JSONValue>> object;
    size_t size();
    JSONValue keys();
    JSONValue inverse_keys();
    void append(JSONValue input);
    void append(std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input);
    void append(std::tuple<std::string, JSONValue> input);
    void append(std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, JSONValue>> input);
    bool contains(JSONValue key);
    JSONValue& operator[](int index);
    JSONValue& operator[](std::string key);
    JSONValue& at(int index);
    JSONValue& at(std::string key);
    bool operator==(JSONValue input);
    void operator=(bool input);
    void operator=(std::string input);
    void operator=(std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input);
    JSONValue(std::string input);
    JSONValue(double input);
    JSONValue(bool input);
    JSONValue(std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input);
    JSONValue(std::vector<JSONValue> input);
    JSONValue(void* null_input);
    bool operator!=(JSONValue input){if(!(input == *this)){return true;}return false;}
    JSONValueType type;
    //template<typename T>
    //T get();
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<detect_number::detect<T>, bool>::type = true>
    T get();
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<detect_string::detect<T>, bool>::type = true>
    T get();
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<detect_chararray::detect<T>, bool>::type = true>
    T get();
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<detect_boolean::detect<T>, bool>::type = true>
    T get();
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<detect_vector::detect<T>, bool>::type = true>
    T get();
    void extend(JSONValue input);
    std::string dump();
private:
    void null_self(){type = JSONValueType::Null;}
};
```

And here are the constructors:

```
JSONValue::JSONValue(double input){
    type = JSONValueType::Number;
    number = input;
}

JSONValue::JSONValue(std::string input){
    type = JSONValueType::String;
    string = input;
}

JSONValue::JSONValue(std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input){
    type = JSONValueType::Object;
    object = std::optional(input);
}
JSONValue::JSONValue(std::vector<JSONValue> input){
    type = JSONValueType::Array;
    array = input;
}
JSONValue::JSONValue(bool input){
    type = JSONValueType::Boolean;
    boolean = input;
}
JSONValue::JSONValue(void* input){
    if(input == nullptr || input == NULL){
        type = JSONValueType::Null;
    }
}
JSONValue array(){
        std::vector<JSONValue> input;
        return JSONValue(input);
}
JSONValue object(){
    std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input;
    return JSONValue(input);
}
```

In my example above, this is the operator function defined:

```
JSONValue& JSONValue::operator[](std::string key){
    switch(type){
        case JSONValueType::Object:{
            JSONValue ks = keys();
            if(!contains(to_json<std::string>(key))){
                json::JSONValue n(nullptr);
                object.value().insert({key, n});
                return object.value().at(key);
            }
            return object.value().at(key);
        }
        case JSONValueType::Array:{
            JSONValue k = keys();
            assert(k.contains(to_json<std::string>(key)));
            for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
                if(at(i).type == JSONValueType::Object && at(i).keys().contains(to_json<std::string>(key)))
                    return at(i)[key];
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    std::cerr<<"Unable to do this for anything other than an object"<<std::endl;    
    null_self();
    return *this;   
}
```

Basically, I want to know how to make the constructors explicit.

Comment: I looks like the data carrying members should be in a `union` instead of in misc `std::optional`s. Each `std::optional<T>` still takes up as much space as a `T` (+1 byte + extra alignment or so)

Comment: To do what you want to do, you have to implement `operator=(double input);` for the JSONvalue structure.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, thank you, it is because I had `void operator=(bool input);` it was automatically overloading it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have identified the root cause, but to elaborate on what's going on here, when you write

```
a["key"] = 4.3;
```

C++ looks for an overload for `operator=` for the `JSONValue` type. It then sees these overloads:

```
void operator=(bool input);
void operator=(std::string input);
void operator=(std::map<std::string, JSONValue> input);
```

There's also the implicitly-defined assignment operator

```
JSONValue& operator=(const JSONValue&);
```

Of these four operators, the one that's preferred is the first (`void operator=(bool)`), and that's the one that's selected.

One option here would simply be to remove all of these explicit assignment operators and just rely on the implicitly-defined one. Without any assignment operators written explicitly, the only options are the default move/copy assignment operators, and when writing

```
a["key"] = 4.3;
```

C++ will try to find some way to construct a `JSONType` object from `4.3` using your conversion constructors. That will lead to overload resolution selecting the right option.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. Let me fix that.